# How to identify ionic compounds

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ionic-compounds, identification

I have a Chemistry lab in which I must design and carry out an experiment to determine the compound in each of eight numbered vials. Each vial contains one of these ionic compounds:

- BaCl<sub>2</sub>
- CaCO<sub>3</sub>
- Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub>
- KI
- NaCl
- NaHCO<sub>3</sub>
- Na<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>
- Pb(NO<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>

Materials:

- Distilled water
- Several microwell reaction plates
- Tooth picks (to stir)
- 8x 1mL Beral style pipets
- The contents of the lab drawer (beakers, test tubes, etc.)

In addition to the materials above, **one** of the following four additional reagents may be used:

- 6M H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>
- 6M HCl
- 6M NaOH
- phenolphthalein indicator solution

I know how to identify a couple of them. For instance, CaCO<sub>3</sub> can be identified by its insolubility in water, but as for the rest, I'm not completely sure. I know some can be identified by how and if they react with other compounds, but I don't know exactly how to go about that.

Comment: What are your ideas for the other compounds?  Please include your attempts in your question.

Comment: I know some can be identified by how and if they react with other compounds, but I don't know exactly how to go about that.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can use phenolphthalein indicator solution, $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ and $\ce{NaHCO3}$ will turn red. Then use 6M $\ce{HCl}$ and the $\ce{NaHCO3}$ bubbles.

$\ce{NaOH}$ to identify $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$: it generates precipitations. Use $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ to identify $\ce{KI}$: generate golden precipitations.

$\ce{H2SO4}$ with $\ce{BaCl2}$ gives white precipitations, $\ce{Na2SO4}$ with $\ce{BaCl2}$ likewise. So the rest is $\ce{NaCl}$.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance that you can use a [Teclu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teclu_burner) or a [Bunsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunsen_burner) burner?

If so, you will need a batch of magnesia ($\ce{MgO}$) sticks too.

Most of the cations can be identified by a **flame test**, since they furnish a typical colour in the "blue" flame of the burners.

- Na: intense yellow
- K: lilac/violet
- Ca: brick red
- Ba: pale green
- Pb: blue/white (I had to look that up, never did it myself)